# ERROR 1054 (42S22) on trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

So what I'm trying to do is build a web application for sports applications (specifically soccer). Right now, I'm having trouble with a trigger that is supposed to update the standings after a match score is recorded. In this example, I have a 'game' table, and a 'standings' table, like so.

```
mysql> describe game;
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sid             | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| fid             | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| lid             | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| htid            | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| atid            | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| date            | date       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| time            | time       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| h_g             | int(11)    | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| a_g             | int(11)    | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| has_been_played | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe standings;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| tid   | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| sid   | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| lid   | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| pld   | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| pts   | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| h_w   | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| h_t   | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| h_l   | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| h_gf  | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| h_ga  | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| a_w   | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| a_t   | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| a_l   | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| a_gf  | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| a_ga  | int(11) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Where h/atid (and tid), fid, sid, and lid are foreign keys to team, field, season, and league tables, respectively.

I want to create a trigger after a game is updated. The current design I am aiming for in this application is that when a "game" is inserted, it has not been "played" yet and when it is updated, then the score is recorded and then the game is then considered "played." So here's a section of the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_standing` AFTER UPDATE ON `game`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  # If a score has been recorded already, we'll reverse the old score
  # before updating the new score.
  IF OLD.has_been_played THEN
    # The Home Team previously recorded a win
    IF OLD.h_g > OLD.a_g THEN
      # Home win
      UPDATE standings
      SET pld = pld - 1,
          h_w = h_w - 1,
          pts = pts - 3,
          h_gf = h_gf - OLD.h_g,
          h_ga = h_ga - OLD.a_g
      WHERE tid = OLD.htid
        AND sid = OLD.sid
        AND lid = OLD.lid;

      # Away loss
      UPDATE standings
      SET pld = pld - 1,
          a_l = a_l - 1,
          a_gf = a_gf - OLD.a_g,
          a_ga = a_ga - OLD.h_g
      WHERE tid = OLD.atid
        AND sid = OLD.sid
        AND lid = OLD.lid;
    ENDIF;
  ENDIF;
END;
```

And for some reason, I'm getting these errors, and I'm not sure why.

```
mysql> source new_trigger_myfam.sql
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 18
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'OLD.atid' in 'where clause'
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ENDIF' at line 1
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ENDIF' at line 1
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1
```

Is there something visibly wrong with my syntax? I understand that I could do the two update queries in one using case/when/then. Essentially, in this snippet of the trigger, I am reversing a previous update, and then there's more code actually making the rest of the update happen. I'm pretty new to triggers, so help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html), the IF block terminator in MySQL is two words: `END IF`.

Comment: Strange, cause even with end if, that line still barks at me.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it with the help of someone else.

I need to wrap a delimiter around the triggers because the first instance of ; means that the entire trigger is "ended", when obviously that is not what I want.

Really stupid if you ask me, but what can you do?